# JavaFX NullPointerException when changing states of components in other Controller?

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, controller, fxmlloader

When i try to clear a LisView or disable a ToggleButton or initialise variable in other Controller i get :

```
<!-- language: lang-none --> 

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafxcyberwind.Choix_ClientController.lambda$initialize$3(Choix_ClientController.java:258)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

There is my code :

```
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Participant.fxml"));
            ParticipantController ctr = loader.getController();
            ctr.pr_al.setSelected(false);//NullPointerException here
            ctr.pr_al.setDisable(true);
            ctr.sp_pr.toBack();
            ctr.li_se.getItems().clear();
            ctr.k = 0;
            loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
            Parent parent = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) e.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            stage.hide();
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            parent.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
                xOffset = event.getSceneX();
                yOffset = event.getSceneY();
            });
            parent.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> {
                stage.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                stage.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
            });
```

Comment: You don’t load the FXML file, so `ctr` is null.

Comment: No i have the FXML file.

Comment: How can i get an instance for the loded controller ?

Comment: You missed my point. You create the loader and set its location, but you don’t use it to load the FXML file. Since the controller class is specified in the FXML file, the loader can’t possibly create the controller without reading the FXML file. So when you call `getController()`, it doesn’t have a controller and returns null.

Comment: Even if you load the FXML file here, you don’t display the UI it defines, so your calls to the controller would just be changing a UI that isn’t displayed, and so they would have no effect. It’s not at all clear from the code you posted what you’re trying to do here.